# Qt installer override message boxes

Tags: c++, qt, qt-installer

With Qt installer framework, we're allowed to customize UI elements of steps but it seems that when it comes to message boxes, which are not really UI elements, the only thing we can do is automatically answer or simply dismiss all of them given to [this page](http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/scripting-qmessagebox.html).

In my configuration, I'd like to display **a custom QMessageBox** when the chosen directory triggers the [TargetDirectoryInUse error](http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/noninteractive.html#message-boxes), or at least **replace the message** displayed in it.
I don't need it to act differently, I still need the installer not to allow installation when clicking OK but I don't like the text in it.

The [Target Directory Page](http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/noninteractive.html#target-directory-page) reveals no information about any signal or callback they would've made accessible either.

Any hint would be appreciated !

Comment: I'd love to be able to quit the installer with an error when a message box shows up at least (for automated installations of Qt) but all I can do is set an external timeout.